# Remove commas from the string using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to remove commas from the string and calculate those amount using JavaScript.

For example, I have those two values:

- 100,000.00
- 500,000.00

Now I want to remove commas from those string and want the total of those amount.

Comment: It's not efficient, but you could always do `"1,000,000.00".split(',").join("")`.

Answer (score 235, accepted):

To remove the commas, you'll need to use [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) on the string.  To convert to a float so you can do the maths, you'll need [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat):

```
var total = parseFloat('100,000.00'.replace(/,/g, '')) +
            parseFloat('500,000.00'.replace(/,/g, ''));
```

Comment: Yep, need to combine `replace` and `parseFloat`. here is quick test case: http://jsfiddle.net/TtYpH/

Comment: It's 2017, is there no way to go to and **from** a locale string? How do you reverse this function? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString. Posted a separate question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41905406/how-to-convert-a-locale-string-currency-back-into-a-number/41905454#41905454

Answer (score 6):

Related answer, but if you want to run clean up a user inputting values into a form, here's what you can do:

```
const numFormatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
  style: "decimal",
  maximumFractionDigits: 2
})

// Good Inputs
parseFloat(numFormatter.format('1234').replace(/,/g,"")) // 1234
parseFloat(numFormatter.format('123').replace(/,/g,"")) // 123

// 3rd decimal place rounds to nearest
parseFloat(numFormatter.format('1234.233').replace(/,/g,"")); // 1234.23
parseFloat(numFormatter.format('1234.239').replace(/,/g,"")); // 1234.24

// Bad Inputs
parseFloat(numFormatter.format('1234.233a').replace(/,/g,"")); // NaN
parseFloat(numFormatter.format('$1234.23').replace(/,/g,"")); // NaN

// Edge Cases
parseFloat(numFormatter.format(true).replace(/,/g,"")) // 1
parseFloat(numFormatter.format(false).replace(/,/g,"")) // 0
parseFloat(numFormatter.format(NaN).replace(/,/g,"")) // NaN
```

Use the international date local via `format`. This cleans up any bad inputs, if there is one it returns a string of `NaN` you can check for. There's no way currently of removing commas as part of the locale *(as of 10/12/19)*, so you can use a regex command to remove commas using `replace`.

`ParseFloat` converts the this type definition from string to number

If you use React, this is what your calculate function could look like:

```
updateCalculationInput = (e) => {
    let value;
    value = numFormatter.format(e.target.value); // 123,456.78 - 3rd decimal rounds to nearest number as expected
    if(value === 'NaN') return; // locale returns string of NaN if fail
    value = value.replace(/,/g, ""); // remove commas
    value = parseFloat(value); // now parse to float should always be clean input

    // Do the actual math and setState calls here
}
```

Answer (score 5):

To remove commas, you will need to use string replace method.

```js
var numberArray = ["1000,00", "23", "11"];

//If String
var arrayValue = parseFloat(numberArray.toString().replace(/,/g, ""));

console.log(arrayValue, "Array into toString")

// If Array

var number = "23,949,333";
var stringValue = parseFloat(number.replace(/,/g, ""));

console.log(stringValue, "using String");
```