# remove special character for a string using javascript?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove commas from the string using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788741/remove-commas-from-the-string-using-javascript)

I want to remove special character in my string while searching . MY string is "It's complicated".
I wnat to remove ' from my string.

Can anybody please help me??

Answer (score 3):

`"It's complicated".replace("'", "");`