# How to convert a locale string (currency) back into a number?

Tags: javascript

I'm using `toLocaleString()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString to convert into a dollar string format, but I'm having trouble reversing the operation. In my case converting back into cents.

`dollarString.split('$')[1] * 100` Messes up as soon as the string has a `,` in it.

**Is there a better way to handle this, than to go through strings removing commas?**

What if I end up using other currencies. Can't I convert in and out of whatever the currency is into a cents representation so I can do math, and then back into some locale?

Comment: replace the `,` with `.` then use `parseFloat` method , for example `var c = parseFloat("10.33")`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25645163/how-do-i-convert-string-to-number-according-to-locale-opposite-of-tolocalestri

Comment: can you just store the other value too?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are in a locale that uses a period as the decimal point, you could use something like this:

```
var dollarsAsFloat = parseFloat(dollarString.replace(/[^0-9-.]/g, ''));
```

The above uses a regular expression to remove everything but digits and the decimal.  The `parsefloat` function will do the rest.

Just be careful.  Some countries do not use comma and decimal the way you do! It is probably best to keep the monetary amount in a float variable, and only format it when actually printing it.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by others, you need to remove (`,`) from the string.

```
dollarString.split('$')[1].replace(/\,/g,'') * 100
```

In case,`dollarString` has only values as `$xx,xxx,xxx$xx,xxx,xxx`, then you may simply remove all (`,`) then split

```
dollarString.replace(/\,/g,'').split('$')[1] * 100
```

Answer (score 1):

Ex:  I decide  to use n digits after dot and comma separator

```
Object.defineProperties(Number.prototype,{
    locale:{
        value:function(n){
           n = n||2
           return  this.toLocaleString('en', {
                         minimumFractionDigits: n, 
                         maximumFractionDigits: n
           });
        }
    }
});
```

/ reverse from string to number /

```
Object.defineProperties(String.prototype,{
    floatLocale:{
        value: function(){
            return parseFloat(this.replace(/,/g,""));
        }
    }
});
```

So `v= 1000.33; v === v.locale().floatLocale();`