# Calculating 2 values from fields but it's not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am calculating 2 fields on a form with values but it seems in some cases it's not working. Here's my javascript. I am adding `$oneTimeCostField` and `$recurringTotalCostField` to get the value into the `$totalRetailAmountField`. Here's the result I am getting when I add say 1,555.00 + 566.00 = the value is 567.00 (?). Any idea what I'm doing wrong? In some cases it works correctly when the values are lower. Thanks, just stumped

```
var $recurringCostField = $('#am_attribute_campaign_addon_monthly_cost_value');
var $recurringTotalCostField = $('#am_attribute_campaign_addon_total_monthly_cost_value');
var $totalRetailAmountField = $('#am_oie_string_total_monthly_cost_value');
var $oneTimeCostField = $('#am_attribute_campaign_addon_one_time_cost_value');

function calcVal() {
    var num1 = $oneTimeCostField.val();
    var num2 = $recurringTotalCostField.val();
    var result = parseFloat(num1) + parseFloat(num2);
    if (!isNaN(result)) {
        $totalRetailAmountField.val(result.toFixed(2));
    }
}
    calcVal();
      $oneTimeCostField.on("keydown keyup", function() {
        calcVal();
     });
      $recurringTotalCostField.on("keydown keyup", function() {
        calcVal();
     });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the commas before parsing:

`var result = parseFloat(num1.replace(/,/g, '')) + parseFloat(num2.replace(/,/g, ''));`

similiar question on this link
[Remove commas from the string using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788741/remove-commas-from-the-string-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

That is because **parseFloat()** converts the string "1,555.00" to the number 1.
To convert it to a proper floating point number, it needs to include a single dot only.

```
console.log(parseFloat("1.555"));
```

Comment: Thanks can you possibly correct my code if you see something wrong?